# Groovy - any way to pass arguments from a closure into an Annotation (on that closure)?

Tags: groovy, annotations

I have some Groovy code of the form:

```
@ConditionalInterrupt({ MyTimeoutClass.myMethod(command, name) })   
def someClosure = { String command, String name ->
```

The code has 'someClosure' annotated; however, I would like to be able to pass the closure arguments into a method called by the Annotation Closure.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What happens when you use the code you posted?

Comment: I "made up" that syntax to illustrate what I was trying to do, if I try that out, I get a 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException" when that code is attempting to execute.

Comment: That annotation is applied at compile time (Groovy AST), you won't have access to the runtime values passed into the closure.

Comment: Thank you!  That is pretty much what I thought - but didn't know those exact details.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept that.